# Webdriver - getting div value using java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Html

```
<div class="rc-anchor-light">
<div id="accessible-status" class="rc-anchor-aria-status" aria-hidden="true">requires verification.</div>
</div>
```

My expected

Extract the text from inside the div "`requires verification.`"

tried below locator, but i'm not getting my expected.

unique id so i tired with id getting empty result

```
String accessText = driver.findElement(By.id("accessible-status")).getText();
```

using class name getting empty result

```
String accessText = driver.findElement(By.className("rc-anchor-aria-status")).getText();
```

Please suggest me how to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

Text content of target `div` node might be generated dynamically. Try to implement ExplicitWait for element with *any* text:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
WebElement divNode = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='accessible-status' and normalize-space()]"));
String accessText = divNode.getText();
```

If element has text from the very beggining, but it is just hidden, `getText()` will not return you text. In this case you may try

```
String accessText = driver.findElement(By.id("accessible-status")).getAttribute("textContent");
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to extract the text **requires verification.** from the div you need to use a *Locator Strategy* to identify the *WebElement* uniquely and induce [*WebDriverWait*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) with [*ExpectedConditions*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) set as [`visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) for the *WebElement* to be *visible* in the *HTML DOM*  and finally use `getAttribute()` method to to extract the text. You can use the following line of code :

```
System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='rc-anchor-light']/div[@class='rc-anchor-aria-status' and @id='accessible-status']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```